# Vertical alignment in a LayoutPanel

Tags: gwt, layout, styling

I use in a gwt application a LayoutPanel with two Buttons inside it. The LayoutPanle has height of 35px; while the Buttons have height of 25px; I want to align vertically the Buttons in the middle of Panel. Much as I have tried, no common styling approach seems to work on it. Either setting vertical-align: middle on the Panel styling or or on the Buttons styling, the Buttons remain top-aligned. What is the proper approach in this case to bring eventually the Buttons in the middle, other than wrapping a HorizontalPanel for each Button inside the LayoutPanel and applying the verticalAlignment on the HorizontalPanel? Here is my code in Uibinder:

```
<g:LayoutPanel styleName="{style.buttonsBar}">
             <g:layer left="30px" width="70px">
                 <g:Button ui:field="createButton" styleName="{style.crdelButton}">Create</g:Button>
                 </g:layer>
                 <g:layer right="30px" width="70px">
                     <g:Button ui:field="deleteButton" styleName="{style.crdelButton}">Delete</g:Button>
                 </g:layer>
        </g:LayoutPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you panel is always 35px high, you have two options:

(1) Set margin on buttons to

margin: 5px 0;

(2) Set the following style to your LayoutPanel:

line-height: 35px;